# std::map with string key and custom value field

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdmap

How to create a `std::map` with `string` key and custom value field.

I want a `std::map` as below:

```
 "Name" "abcd"
 "age"  "50"
 "Address" "Street" "xxxx"
           "PIN"    "xxxx"
           "District" "xxxx"
 "Gender" "Male"
```

So my all my fields except the third one are `string,string` type. But the address is itself an another map with `string string` pair.

How do I create such a map in c++ ?

Comment: Your values have to be of a type capable of representing a string or a map from strings to strings.

Comment: I think you should model this as a class and not as a map.

Comment: You are describing a record a.k.a a `struct` (or a `class`) not a map. If you really need need a map then you should probably use a `std::map<string, variant>` using a variant from Boost or Qt for example. If you think you need amap, you should probably explain why. The optimal solution depends on the reasons why you would need a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the mapped type to be something that can store either a string or a map. One way would be to use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html):

```
typedef boost::variant<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> Value;

typedef std::map<std::string, Value> TheMapYouWouldUse;
```

Read the documentation I've linked to learn how to access the values.

An alternative would be to provide your own restricted solution. Perhaps something like this (somewhat hacky):

```
class Value
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string> values;

public:
  std::string& asString()
  { return values[""]; }

  std::map<std::string, std::string>& asMap()
  { return value; }
};
```

The interface would of course be tuned to suit your real needs.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.
You could use a map with a vector, where each index from your vector represents one item.

code not tested just typed

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> items;
items["Address"].push_back("xxxx")
```

Or you could use a map of list

```
std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string>> items;
items["Address"].push_back("xxxx")
```

Or you could use a map of maps

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> items;
std::map<std::string, std::string> subItems;
subItems.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("Street", "xxxx");
subItems.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>("District", "xxxx");
items["Address"] = subItems;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I am using the first method where I put the value "Street" ( It is actually the key for value "xxxx"). Also on second method ( map of map) How I add Name field. It is only have single value.

Comment: Option one implies that Street is index 0, District would be index 1 and so on.

Comment: @user2621310 You realize that your are re-implementing `struct` right ? I mean i've seen some stubborn people trying to re-implement vector or string, but struct, this is a first.

Comment: @Félix Cantournet Not exactly a struct when you look at his example. But structs could also be used to solve his issue.

Comment: @user743414 How is this not a struct/class with one member (Address) being another struc or a std::map ? Please do not encourage this. You are reimplementing struct, again this is less flexible, less safe, more complex and slower. Why would you do this ?

Comment: @user743414: I can't use struct to solve this issue.Its a little bit weird. I am Forces to use map only.

Comment: @Félix Cantournet And what's with "name" and "age"? You're taking a small piece from his example. We don't know if he want's to search. We don't know how many rows he had. So using a struct could be slower and less flexible...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a map, you should create a class representing your person objects.

```
enum class Gender
{
male,
female
};

class ZipCode
{
// ...
};

class Address
{
  Address(std::string const& s, std::string const& p, std::string const& d):
     street(s),
     pin(p),
     district(d)
  {
  }

private:
  std::string street;
  std::string pin;
  std::string district;  
};

class Person
{
public:
  Person(std::string const& n, Gender d, Address const& a):
    name(n),
    gender(g),
    address(a)
  {
  }

  // now add methods operating on the data.

private:
  std::string name;
  Gender gender;
  Address address;
};
```

Instead of creating a class with just getters and setters, try to find reasonable services for methods. Try to avoid setters in general.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I think it is a design issue rather than a language issue.